# Can I use Samsung fingerprint SDK for my own app?

Tags: android, fingerprint, samsung-mobile-sdk

I want to create an android online voting system app. This app will use Samsung fingerprint scanner to verify voter identity - valid or not - on our server. Is it possible for Samsung fingerprint scanner SDK to verify the fingerprint by checking on our server rather than the android SQLite database?

Comment: ... only for Samsung, brand specific and model specific owners... What a great app!

Comment: how do you match fingerprint in SQLite or another SQL base on server ?
Do you know what's a template or a minutiae ? and how to match fingerprints ?

Answer (score 0):

Samsung provide a [Pass SDK](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy#pass)

> Pass SDK allows you to use fingerprint recognition features in your
>   application. With Pass SDK, you can provide reinforced security, since
>   you can identify whether the current user actually is the authentic
>   owner of the device.

If you want to get fingerprint (template or image), it's not possible with Samsung device. You could only check owner of device.